# What model to predict GYM Leavers based on recent GYM Joiners? HELP!! Time series vs Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: python, time-series, regression, prediction, arima

I work in the gym space, and I'm trying to predict the numbers of gym leavers we will see next month, the following month etc.

The number of leavers are directly be impacted by the number of joiners we had 13 months ago (for a 12 month contract) or 4 months ago (for a 3 month) contract. As you need to give a months notice.

There is some seasonality in Jan/Sept, but ultimately the type of contract a member joins only and length is the biggest contribution to how long they'd likely stay.

We have over a hundred permutations on contract types and length.

What is the best way to model this in python, and which methods.

I've created a proof of concept model in excel, which looks at historic churn rates, a month 1/2/3etc by contract, and can apply that to our current member mix and their tenure to predict how many will leave this month but it's extremely messy on lots of worksheets. But it is accurate, and outside irregular macro events is very accurate in predicting Leavers within the next month..

I've tried a linear regression based on the leaver volume this month, against all the Joiners in t-1, t-2... t-64.. but it spits out a bunch of co-efficients which don't provide any reasonable number. Some are (+)ive and some (-)ive. But i thought over a longer enough period the numbers of joiners could show estimate leavers.

I've thought Time series next, but struggle to understand how to set the data up to run that. As i have some many contract mixes, and in one way, i need to look at the data and say, this person is on this contract, has been with us X months, so has this chance of leaving.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for narrow, specific questions about the practice of software development (which is to say, concretely writing code). For picking an algorithm, you probably want [stats.se] (the Stack Exchange site on statistics) instead.

Comment: Thanks Charles - i'll try that. Appreciate the message.